# Why do we need both "useParams" and "getAPI"?

Tags: reactjs, routes

From my understanding, useParams hooks would allow me to take parameter from another route.

Why then do we need to do `axios.get` as well, to make the fetching work?
Isn't it also just fetching the data (params) available on an API?

See picture for examples.

Thank you, I appreciate your time.

[image]

Comment: There is no relation whatsoever between `useParam()` and `axios`. `useParam()` allows you to get a param from a route _on your React app_, while with `axios` you're making a AJAX request to an external API. In your example you use the value of the `id` param on your route to request a resource on an API: the value might be the same but they are different params.

Comment: Thank you, this helped for some more comprehension. However,  I useParams to receive the ids from a data set on another route in my React app which in turn fetches the same API as this route. Isnt useParams then not redundant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I can't really follow your use case.

`useParams()` is a hook from `react-router` and its sole purpose is to return dynamic params from the current rendered URL in your React application. What you do then with this value is up to you and, of course, you can use it as a param to fetch data from an external API. But this fetching has nothing to do with `useParams()` (or `react-router`), you do that with `axios` or `fetch()` or whatever. `useParams()` doesn't make any AJAX call.

Apparently in your specific case the value of the `id` param in your rendered React route is the same value you use on a API (`jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`) to retrieve a resource. That's fine, but it's a peculiarity in your application design and doesn't change the fact that the two params (the one in your rendered route and the one passed to the external API) are different, unrelated things.